# Different display of listing's background (Texmaker internal PDF viewer & Adobe Reader)

Tags: listings, texmaker, backgrounds, adobe

I have following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{color, eso-pic, tikz}   % Create commutative diagrams
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{light-gray}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\definecolor{light-light-gray}{rgb}{0.98,0.98,0.98}

\lstdefinestyle{customc}{
  belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
  breaklines=true,
  numbers=left,
  backgroundcolor=\color{light-light-gray},
  language=C,
  frame=l,
  framesep=4.5mm,
  framexleftmargin=2.5mm,
  fillcolor=\color{light-gray},
  rulecolor=\color{blue},
  numberstyle=\normalfont\tiny\color{black}
}

\lstset{escapechar=@,style=customc}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Texmaker + XeLaTeX + internal PDF viewer output:

[image]

And that's great. I wanna keep it that way. But when I open the file in Adobe Reader I get:

[image]

No background at all. I've checked that background would be displayed, when gray would be set to very dark one (rgb 0.8 0.8 0.8 or less), but that's not the way.

Maybe some extra transparence settings should be added?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Works fine for me (windows, current adobe reader). Check in the adobe options/accessibility (?)  if you enabled special colors.

Comment: As in almost any cases, when a line/background seems to be vanished in Adobe Reader, it's a Reader's feature, i.e. by zooming in the effect should be there!

Comment: Can we close this question?

Comment: As Ulrike Fischer noticed: options/accessibility, checkbox 'Replace Document Colors' did the work. Thanks for help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was caused by viewer preferences rather than the TeX side.